# settings and switching to external pgsql db

Tags: database

I am working with Drupal 7.3.4 and attempting to follow the instructions of changing settings.php so that I can switch to a pgsql DB within a module and then switch back to the default mysql after doing a query.

I have set up in the settings.php file with the following format:

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => '',
      'username' => '',
      'password' => '',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
  'custom_db' =>
  array (
    'default' =>
    array (
      'database' => 'custom_db',
      'username' => 'dbuser',
      'password' => 'pass',
      'host' => 'urltoservice',
      'port' => '5432',
      'driver' => 'pgsql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Now I am trying the process of switching to this DB in a module and verifying that the driver is changing.

```
db_set_active('custom_db');
//Get the currently active DB driver
drupal_set_message(db_driver());
db_set_active();
```

But, when I print the driver it is not switching to pgsql as expected.  I am pretty sure it is still pointing to the default mysql db.  Any ideas of what I may be doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Derek

Comment: try outputting the return value from the second call to db_set_active - it should return the current DB (which at that point would be custom_db) to confirm.  Also, as always with Drupal, did you clear the cache?

Answer (score 0):

first check whether you are executing your query before  doing `db_set_active();` because this function call will set your db to default drupal db.

so you should go like this:

```
db_set_active('custom_db');
```

// execute your query related stuff here

then at last switch to your default db by `db_set_active();`

Comment: Thanks for this tip.  I verified that I am executing my query to PGSQL before doing db_set_active().